# JS: Access object variable inside sub-object

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I guess this have been both asked and answered before, but I don't really know what to search for.

Anyway, lets say we've got the following JavaScript:

```
var foo = {
   myVar : 'Hello',
   bar : function() {
      //Fetch the myVar variable
   }
}
```

How do I access the variable where mentioned?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var foo = {
   myVar : 'Hello',
   bar : function() {
      alert(this.myVar);
   }
}
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/opabef)

Comment: Seems to work the way you write it! How would the alert line look like if the foo object is in another object?

Comment: I saved your JS. You had a = instead of :. It works now. You should read documentation about object literals in JS if you want to understand what happens behind the scene :)

Comment: Ops, as simple as that, didn't notice it. Thank you. :)